# Make column and main content stay on left or right, as browser is resized

Tags: css

I have a floating right column, that successfully pushes the main content area right when the browser width is reduced.  CSS:

```
div.bigSquare 
{
    min-width: 200px; 
    max-width: 400px;
    background-color:silver;
}

div.floatRight
{
    float:right;
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h2>Fun with positions, widths, and heights</h2>

<div class="floatRight">Right square</div>

<div class="bigSquare">The main content area has very very very very very 
very very very very very very very very very very very very very very 
very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very         
very very very very 
very very very many words in it.
</div>
```

([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hno6ftzy/))

The problem is that when I shrink the browser width sufficiently, the text of the main content area spills over underneath the right column:

[image]

I would like to keep the main content always left of the right column.  What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered `flex`? If you wrap the content area and sidebar in a parent element you can try something like this: `.flex-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}`   
https://jsfiddle.net/hno6ftzy/4/

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you `float` an element, do not forget that it has to be `clear`ed, or you would see unpredictable behaviour for the elements that follow it.

You have to specify `overflow` property, or `clear` the `float`s and in doing so create a new `block formatting context` to let the browser know that it can stop floating the elements then.

See example below when I specify `overflow: auto` on `bigSquare`- note that on smaller screen `bigSquare` will fall below `floatRight`:

```css
div.bigSquare {
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: silver;
  overflow: auto;
}
div.floatRight {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<h2>Fun with positions, widths, and heights</h2>

<div class="floatRight">Right column</div>

<div class="bigSquare">The main content area has very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very many words in it.
</div>
```

**Solution:**

So in your case, here is the solution- float your `bigSquare` too and `clear` the float after `floatRight` using this:

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

Note you have to specify `width`s for the floated containers too- otherwise it will wrap (come one below the other)- so specifying a width for `bigSquare` to adjust for the `100px` of `floatRight`:

```
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
```

snippet below:

```css
div.bigSquare {
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: silver;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
div.floatRight {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<h2>Fun with positions, widths, and heights</h2>

<div class="floatRight">Right column</div>

<div class="bigSquare">The main content area has very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very many words in it.
</div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

**Simplest solution:**

Don't use floats- use a `flexbox`:

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse; /*wrap if window width less than combined min-widths*/
}
div.bigSquare {
  background-color: silver;
  flex: 1 0 200px;/*set min-width*/
}
div.floatRight {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
  flex: 1 0 100px;/*set min-width*/
}
```

```html
<h2>Fun with positions, widths, and heights</h2>

<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="floatRight">Right column</div>

  <div class="bigSquare">The main content area has very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very many words in it.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The options for overflow make the right column appear _above_ the main content area, with reduced browser width.  I had much better success with the flexbox -- tx -- but still have some problems.  It doesn't give me columns in my IE 10 browser, even if I add the `-ms-flex` property in the same places as `flex` (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp).  Adding `-webkit-flex` for Safari makes the columns appear above/below each other, even in Chrome, if it comes last (no problem if it comes first).  I wonder if there's a solution that works more generally.

Comment: actually the float solution you have above (along with setting width and clearing float) does not do that as you say... for flex-box solution remove the `flex-wrap` and the `flex` rules setting the wrap and min-width settings and it will not come one below the other...

Answer (score 0):

Adding `overflow: auto` to `div.bigSquare` will do the trick.

Setting the `overflow` property forces the `div` to create for block formatting context which means that the content will not interact with any floating elements outside of the block.

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting

```css
div.bigSquare {
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: silver;
  overflow: auto;
}
div.floatRight {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<h2>Fun with positions, widths, and heights</h2>

<div class="floatRight">Right column</div>

<div class="bigSquare">The main content area has very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very many words in it.
  The main content area has very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very many words in it.
</div>
```