# CSS: Display: inline-block;

Tags: html, css, html-table, menu, display

I have a problem. I have to do this.
 [image: 1]

but I get this

[image: 2]

I think I have to disable somewhere: `display: inline-block` but in all the places I tried It doesn't work? Does anyone know how to make them one by one? First boxes are a menu, second tables. That is, I have to put the table under the menu. But how?

```css
body {
  
}

.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.menu-item {
  background: cornsilk;
  color: crimson;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: black;
}

.menu-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: crimson;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-item a:hover {
  background: crimson;
  color: cornsilk;
}

section {
  display: inline-block;
}

article {
  width: 160px;
  background: whitesmoke;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: left;
}

aside {
  width: 160px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: whitesmoke;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.text {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="cadetblue">
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#"> Link 1 </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#"> Link 2 </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#"> Link 3 </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#"> Link 4 </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#"> Link 5 </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section>
  <article>
    <div class="text"> This is the left column </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </article>
</section>
<section>
  <aside>
    <div class="text"> This is the right column </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </aside>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: Add `overflow: hidden` to your `.menu` item - possible guidance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39311775/make-column-and-main-content-stay-on-left-or-right-as-browser-is-resized/39313556#39313556)

Comment: add `width:100%` to `nav`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clear: both` for `menu::after` to move elements after it down below like so:

```css
body {
  
}

.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.menu::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.menu-item {
  background: cornsilk;
  color: crimson;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: black;
}

.menu-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: crimson;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-item a:hover {
  background: crimson;
  color: cornsilk;
}

section {
  display: inline-block;
}

article {
  width: 160px;
  background: whitesmoke;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: left;
}

aside {
  width: 160px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: whitesmoke;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.text {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="cadetblue">
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#"> Link 1 </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#"> Link 2 </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#"> Link 3 </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#"> Link 4 </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#"> Link 5 </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section>
  <article>
    <div class="text"> This is the left column </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </article>
</section>
<section>
  <aside>
    <div class="text"> This is the right column </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </aside>
</section>
</body>
```