# float left moving wrong to place

Tags: css, html, media-queries

I am improving my css skills on w3schools, my question is what is the 
    reason `.col-2` is under `.col-6`?

Isn't it suppose to be under `.col-3`?

I have put float left so `.col-2` should go under `.col-3`, for over 1 hour looking for reason.

The [code](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G263VQV9ECJ0) will not run until you click the "Run" button in the Tryit Editor.

Comment: add `clear: left` to `col-2` or insert `<div style="clear: both"></div>` before that - a possible guidance can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39311775/make-column-and-main-content-stay-on-left-or-right-as-browser-is-resized/39313556#39313556)

Comment: @kukkuz that is working but whats the reaon it goes under col-6 ?

Comment: see the answer I have linked, you should *clear* the `float` you have applied if you are going to start on a new line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `col-2` and `col-3` to this:

```
.col-3{
  float: left;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.col-2{
  float: left;
  padding: 0 15px;    
  clear: left;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.col-3 {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.col-2 {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 15px;
  clear: left;
}

html {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
}

.header {
  background-color: #9933cc;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  background-color: #33b5e5;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.menu li:hover {
  background-color: #0099cc;
}

.aside {
  background-color: #33b5e5;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.footer {
  background-color: #0099cc;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 15px;
}


/* For mobile phones: */

[class*="col-"] {
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* For desktop: */
  .col-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Chania</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3 menu">
    <ul>
      <li>The Flight</li>
      <li>The City</li>
      <li>The Island</li>
      <li>The Food</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6">
    <h1>The City</h1>
    <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-2">
    <div class="aside">
      <h2>What?</h2>
      <p>Chania is a city on the island of Crete.</p>
      <h2>Where?</h2>
      <p>Crete is a Greek island in the Mediterranean Sea.</p>
      <h2>How?</h2>
      <p>You can reach Chania airport from all over Europe.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how the content respond to the resizing.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: why it goes under col-6 ? while its left ?

Comment: I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want every box to sit next to each other put in col 6 aswell float: left